# Activiti process migration from one server to another

Tags: activiti

I had taken backup of an ubuntu system which had activiti on it with many processes in it. I successfully restored the backup on another system and I can also access the activiti UI.  But I don't see any processes there. Where are the activiti processes stored / come from?

Comment: They are stored in the [configured database](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#databaseConfiguration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activiti process state is store in the database.
If the database was resident on the same server you restored and you are still able to connect, then your processes should still be present. If the database is elsewhere, make sure connectivity is still correct and your processes should be restored.